# Do all orthogonal matrices satisfy both $Q^TQ = I$ and $QQ^T = I$?

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

Some definitions of orthogonal matrix (for instance, [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)) use the definition:

$$
Q^TQ=QQ^T=I
$$

While other definitions (for instance, [on Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalMatrix.html)) only include one of the products:

$$
QQ^T = I
$$

I remember reading that $Q^TQ$ implies $QQ^T$ for orthogonal matrices, which would explain why some definitions don't list both of the products, but it is not immediately obvious to me why this is the case. From what I understand, an orthogonal matrix is a matrix whose columns are orthogonal unit vectors (i.e. $||z_i||_2^2 = 1$ and $z_i \cdot z_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$), which directly leads to the identity $Q^TQ = I$. However, I don't see why $QQ^T = I$ is necessarily true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why, if a matrix $Q$ is orthogonal, then $Q^T Q = I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766669/why-if-a-matrix-q-is-orthogonal-then-qt-q-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that if $AB = I$ then $B=A^{-1}$ and so $BA = I$.

So if $QQ^T = I$ then $Q^T = Q^{-1}$ and so $Q^TQ=I$.

Comment: First line is true when $A$ and $B$ are square. $Q$ is required to be square by definition, so second line follows from the first.

Comment: Of course! That's what I meant!

Comment: Do both of the statements $AA^{-1} = I$ **and** $A^{-1}A = I$ always hold for an invertible matrix $A$? Is it possible to have one but not the other?

Comment: Yes they do! That's because $\left(GL_n(\mathbb{K}), \cdot \right)$ is a group

Answer (score 0):

For an orthogonal matrix $Q$ we have

$$Q^{-1}=Q^T \iff QQ^T=Q^TQ=I$$